# Set priority color of list element when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

So my dilemma is that I have a page that has a to-do list style input on it with radio buttons that determine the priority level of the thing to do.

Here is the HTML portion:

```
<p style="">A to-do list</p>

<ol class="ch5">

</ol>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
    <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="txtAdd" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
</p>
<p>Set Priority</p>
<p>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>
        High</label>
        <br/>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>
        Meduim</label>
        <br/>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>
        Low</label>
        <br/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add a value" onClick="chapter05()" />
</p>
```

Here's the script:

```
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[0];

var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
list.appendChild(entry);
```

And here's the CSS:

```
    .hiP {
color: red;
    }

    .medP {
        color: blue;
    }

    .lowP {
        color: green;
    }

    .ch5 {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
```

What I've been trying to accomplish is that if you type something in the text box to be put into the list and click a priority radio button, whatever is put into the list shows up either red, blue, or green depending on priority (red being high, blue being medium, green being low). I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with the color class values, loop over buttons to find the selected one and set the item color with the corresponding value:

```js
function chapter05() {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[0];
  btn_colors = {
    'hi': 'hiP',
    'med': 'medP',
    'low': 'lowP'
  }
  radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      btn_selected_color = (btn_colors[radios[i].value]);
      break;
    }
  }
  var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = btn_selected_color;
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
  list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```css
.hiP {
  color: red;
}

.medP {
  color: blue;
}

.lowP {
  color: green;
}

.ch5 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p style="">A to-do list</p>

<ol class="ch5">

</ol>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
  <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="txtAdd" size="50" maxlength="50" />
</p>
<p>Set Priority</p>
<p>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>
        High</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>
        Medium</label>
  <br/>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>
        Low</label>
  <br/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add a value" onClick="chapter05()" />
</p>
```

Comment: You're welcome... Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)